# Django + Docker best practice: use runserver or wsgi.py?

Tags: django, docker

I've been reading a lot of blog posts (like [this one](https://medium.com/backticks-tildes/how-to-dockerize-a-django-application-a42df0cb0a99)) on how to deploy Django in a containerized Docker environment.

They all use the `runserver` command in the `docker-compose.yml`.

Even the [Docker documentation does this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/).

This suprises me, since using the Django web server is [not recommended for production](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#runserver)!

What **is** recommended is [pointing the webserver to wsgi.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/).

However, none of the articles I've found on Django and Docker explain **why** they use `runserver` instead of pointing apache or nginx to `wsgi.py`.

Why would all these articles use the built-in Django development webserver to handle requests, instead of a full blown webserver like apache or nginx?

Isn't the point of using containers in development, to keep that environment as close to production as possible? Then why build a not-production-ready environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aim of most guides including [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/) you given is to give you a `ABC` guide to containerize your django applicaiton quickly with docker.

When you decided to read these guides, you are certainly ansumed as experienced django developer, but a new docker user. So the emphasis of these article will not tell you how to use production server(like uwsgi, gunicorn) to manage your django application, because it assumes your are familiar with that.

As a new docker user, it will put more effort to tell you how to dockerize them in container with a start django project. Then, a simple hello-world-like project with development django http server will be the most suitable option.

But, you still need to use `uwsgi, gunicorn` etc to deploy you apps, E.g. https://hub.docker.com/r/dockerfiles/django-uwsgi-nginx

Comment: That makes sense. 

I'd assume at least one of the articles would mention as much though.